# Expansion of integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How can I expand the integral

\begin{equation}
\int_{t}^{\infty}\frac{\exp(-x)}{x}dx
\end{equation}
 to compute it numerically.

Comment: what do you mean by "expand the integral"?

Comment: See exponential integral (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral)

Comment: You mean using Taylor series ? Like
$$
\int_{t}^\infty \sum_{i=0}^\infty (-1)^i x^{i-1}/i!
$$ ?

Comment: Are we in the range $t\gg 1$ or $t\in(0,1)$?

Comment: Long story short: series expansion for small values of $t$, continued fraction for large values of $t$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an [exponential integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral) with known series expansion:

$$\int_t^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-x}}x~\mathrm dx=-\gamma-\ln(t)-\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(-t)^k}{k\cdot k!}$$

Other such approximations may be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral#Approximations).

Comment: (+1) This is the way to go if $t$ is close to $0$. If $t\gg 1$ the continued fraction representation provides a faster technique for numerical evaluation. Our answers complete each other.

Comment: Thanks for you comment @JackD'Aurizio

Answer (score 2):

Assuming $t>0$ we have
$$ I(t)=\int_{t}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{x e^x} = \frac{1}{te^t}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{\left(1+\frac{x}{t}\right)e^x}$$
and 
$$ \frac{1}{te^t}=\frac{1}{te^t}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{e^x}>I(t)>\frac{1}{t e^t}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{dx}{e^{\frac{x}{t}}e^x} = \frac{1}{(t+1)e^t} $$
might be good enough for pratical purposes. If you require a greater accuracy, you might use the continued fraction representation:

$$ I(t) = \frac{e^{-t}}{(t+1)-\frac{1}{(t+3)-\frac{4}{(t+5)-\frac{9}{(t+7)-\frac{16}{(9+t)+\ldots}}}}} $$

Comment: Hm... this looks slightly different from the continued fraction on the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral#Approximations)

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: they are indeed equivalent - http://functions.wolfram.com/GammaBetaErf/ExpIntegralEi/10/

Answer (score 0):

The function you are integrating is decays quite quick. So let $f(x) = \frac{\exp(-x)}{x}$, choose small $\Delta x$ and just compute:

$$\sum\limits_0^Mf(t + n\Delta x)\Delta x$$

where $M$ is some big number (the idea is that there is no point to compute the values all the way to infinity since you will be adding zero's.)

How to check if your $\Delta x$ is fine? Make is twice as small and recompute - if not much changed then you are fine. How to make sure your $M$ is big enough? Make it twice as big and recompute!

Comment: This is effective only if $t\gg 1$. $f(x)=\frac{1}{x e^x}$ has a non-integrable singularity in a right neighbourhood of zero, hence for small values of $t$ SBA's strategy is way superior.